# Download links in Blazor

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I'm programatically creating links to download files of different formats like .csv and .yml.

My code is

```
<a href="/organs/@organ/@policy/@folder.Name/@file.Name" download>@file.Name</a>
```

so lets say these links get created:

- https://localhost:44372/organs/Heart-Lung/03-15-2020/data/fakedata.yml
- https://localhost:44372/organs/Heart-Lung/03-15-2020/data/testdata.csv

the .csv works as it should, I click and it downloads. the .yml however opens a new web page at that link and then says that it can't be found

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong, is there a way force it to download or should I be doing this a different way?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using javascript to do this, based on https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/blazor-jsinterop-save-file/

most of the code is the same, but I changed the link to this to pass in the variable and to keep it as a clickable link that doesn't go anywhere

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" @onclick=@(() => DownloadFile(file.FullName))>@file.Name</a>
```